WireGuard on Windows is enabling File and Printer Sharing on new tunnels by default. How to stop this?
WireGuard on Windows, when it creates a new tunnel, is enabling File and Printer Sharing by default, as well as all sorts of automated discovery. It doesn't cause the public/private status of that connection to be queried.
Even turning off the particular services has no lasting effect, as WireGuard dynamically creates the adapter every time it activates a tunnel.
For some tunnels this is appropriate. For the case of public VPN services, this is highly inappropriate.
How do I make it a) ask the status on tunnel activation, or b) assume "public" for a particular connection?

WireGuard on Windows, when it creates a new tunnel, is enabling File and Printer Sharing by default - I have 3 Windows computers (2 x Windows 11, 1 x Windows 10) - none of them enable file and print sharing on the Wireguard network, which is set as a Public network by default

Well, if it always assumed Public that would be a problem for my private ones.  But why the behaviour difference between our systems, I don't know.  Does it take the default from the underlying physical network?  The physical network I'm on is private.  Or does it have different behaviour based on allowed IPs?

Does it take the default from the underlying physical network? - no, my physical network is Private

If the WireGuard tunnel name is wg0, you can run this PowerShell command as Administrator to change its network profile to public:
PS> Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias wg0 -NetworkCategory Public

This setting will be persistent -- as long as you don't add or remove any peers to your configuration, and you don't change the AllowedIPs setting for any peers (as those things change the interface GUID).
If you want to run this command every time the WireGuard tunnel starts up, do these 3 things (as Administrator):

Allow WireGuard to execute scripts:
 > reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WireGuard /v DangerousScriptExecution /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f


Allow unrestricted execution of PowerShell scripts:
 PS> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted


Add a PostUp script to the [Interface] section of the tunnel's configuration:
 PostUp = powershell -Command "Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias wg0 -NetworkCategory Public"




For an alternative way to block sharing, you could use custom Windows Defender Firewall rules to explicitly block inbound access through WireGuard to the various services on your computer.
The following PowerShell command would add a custom firewall rule to block all inbound access through the wg0 tunnel (run it as Administrator):
PS> New-NetFirewallRule `
    -Name wg0all `
    -DisplayName "All-In Block wg0" `
    -Group "Custom" `
    -Enabled True `
    -Direction Inbound `
    -Action Block `
    -InterfaceAlias wg0

If you want to block inbound access only to certain services listening on specific ports on your computer, you could add firewall rules just for those specific ports (like SMB access to TCP port 445):
PS> New-NetFirewallRule `
    -Name wg0smb `
    -DisplayName "File and Printer Sharing SMB-In Block wg0" `
    -Group "Custom" `
    -Enabled True `
    -Direction Inbound `
    -Action Block `
    -Protocol TCP `
    -LocalPort 445 `
    -InterfaceAlias wg0

See this WireGuard and Windows Defender Firewall article for more examples of firewall rules.
